# Equal to x but less then y

Tags: javascript, equality

If the number is 10 or less then it gets replaced by Answer is here #1.

But how to do this...
If the number is 10 or less but if the number is 30 or more then the text gets replaced by Answer is here #1.

I know i can add the same code just change >= but i want all in one for my purpouse.

```html
<table>
<tr><td id="X">10</td></tr>
<tr><td id="X">20</td></tr>
<tr><td id="X">30</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
var tdList = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i< tdList.length; i++){ 
  if(parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())<='10' && tdList[i].getAttribute('id') == "X")
  tdList[i].innerHTML = 'Answer is here #1' 
}
</script>
```

Comment: "id" attribute values should be unique across the whole page if you don't like weird things happening.

Comment: Checking `<= '10'` won't work the way you are expecting.  You need to use an integer `10` not a string

Comment: The code works as i want it for my purpouse.
But need the add the function i wrote in the first post only.

Comment: `parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())<='10'` while this works, it's redundant to parse the value as int then compare it to a string. Why not just compare thee `tdList[i]...` value to '10'? Why do you need to `parseInt`?

Answer (score 0):

> But how to do this... If the number is 10 or less but if the number is
>   30 or more then the text gets replaced by Answer is here #1.

`if(parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())<= 10 || parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim() >= 30)`

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes but the script scips this part `|| parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim() >= 30)`

Comment: What do you mean skips? If the number is less than 10, then the whole if condition will evaluate to true. The same also applies if the number is bigger than 30.

Answer (score 0):

This worked somehow dont really understand how but yes it worked.

```html
<table>
<tr><td id="X">0</td></tr>
<tr><td id="X">10</td></tr>
<tr><td id="X">100</td></tr>
</table>

<script>
var tdList = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i< tdList.length; i++){ 
  if(parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())< 9 && tdList[i].getAttribute('id') == "X")
  tdList[i].innerHTML = 'Answer is here 1' 
}
</script>

<script>
var tdList = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i< tdList.length; i++){ 
  if(parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())>= 10 && parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())<= 99 && tdList[i].getAttribute('id') == "X")
  tdList[i].innerHTML = 'Answer is here 2' 
}
</script>

<script>
var tdList = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i< tdList.length; i++){ 
  if(parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())>= 100 && parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())<= 200 && tdList[i].getAttribute('id') == "X")
  tdList[i].innerHTML = 'Answer is here 3' 
}
</script>
```